# ANDROID: is it possible to replace library file of Android OS through an application(.apk)?

Tags: android, android-ndk, apk, patch, android-source

We have made some changes in the "skia" library of Android OS (Froyo) and it works well in emulator.
It also worked when we pushed (replaced) the corresponding .so files in to a device.

Now we want to provide this service to the end users. Is it possible to make an application(apk) that people install to perform this task?

If not possible, then what is the best way we can provide the service to others?

Comment: Totally agree with yury. Submit the patch to Google code review. They will incorporate it in their update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have created a useful functionality that will be useful for a range of users you can submit your patch to Google code review (you can read how to do this [here](http://source.android.com/source/submit-patches.html))

Answer (score 2):

I believe this would only be possible if the app has root access or you distributed a ROM to your users yourselves.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot, unfortunately, unless

- you are the device manufacturer (or Google)
- you are developing a replacement system image, or target only rooted devices